# How is it possible that we install vCenter server in windows even if its type1 hypervisor?

Tags: vmware, esxi, hypervisor, vsphere

My friend installed VCenter server in windows server 2016. I am confused, How can he install it over any OS. it must be installed on bare metal as its type-1 hypervisor.

Comment: vSphere (web client) and the discontinued desktop client are not operating systems.  VCenter is something you install within an OS (along with SQL Server) which is configured to control ESXi hosts.  There is also a VCenter appliance which isn't applicable here.

Answer (score 3):

VCenter is the management application for ESXi and can be installed on lots of different host types.

ESXi is the hypervisor and must run on its own system.

From this article: http://www.mustbegeek.com/difference-between-vsphere-esxi-and-vcenter/

> ESXi is the virtualization server. It is type 1 hypervisor. All the virtual machines or Guest OS are installed on ESXi server.

.

> vCenter server is similar to vSphere client but it’s a server with more power. vCenter server is installed on Windows Server or Linux Server. VMware vCenter server is a centralized management application that lets you manage virtual machines and ESXi hosts centrally. vSphere client is used to access vCenter Server and ultimately manage ESXi servers. vCenter server is compulsory for enterprises to have enterprise features like vMotion, VMware High Availability, VMware Update Manager and VMware Distributed Resource Scheduler (DRS).